# Mathematica Stackexchange editing toolbar

Tags: support, site-tools

I have been away for a while, so I preface this question with an apology if it is trivial. In answering there used to be an add on/tool to that would allow Wolfram reference hyperlinks, automate Wolfram symbols.This added to standard editing menu. I have changed systems and cannot find how to implement this functionality.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you. I am away from computer but I believe this does answer my question.